# Why do I need the type annotation here?

Tags: rust

In this leetcode invert binary tree problem, I'm trying to borrow a node wrapped in an Rc mutably. Here is the code.

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
impl Solution {
    pub fn invert_tree(root: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>) -> Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>> {
        let mut stack: Vec<Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>> = vec![root.clone()];
        while stack.len() > 0 {
            if let Some(node) = stack.pop().unwrap() {
                let n: &mut TreeNode = &mut node.borrow_mut();
                std::mem::swap(&mut n.left, &mut n.right);
                stack.extend(vec![n.left.clone(), n.right.clone()]);
            }
        }
        root
    }
}
```

If I change the line `let n: &mut TreeNode` to just `let n = &mut node.borrow_mut()`, I get a compiler error on the next line, "cannot borrow `*n` as mutable more than once at a time"
It seems like the compiler infers n to be of type `&mut RefMut<TreeNode>`, but it all works out when I explicitly say it is `&mut TreeNode`. Any reason why?

Comment: Note: instead of annotating the type you could also do a reborrow: `let n = &mut *node.borrow_mut();` (add the `*`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A combination of borrow splitting and deref-coercion causes the seemingly identical code to behave differently.

The compiler infers `n` to be of type `RefMut<TreeNode>`, because that's [what `borrow_mut` actually returns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut):

> ```
> pub fn borrow_mut(&self) -> RefMut<'_, T>
> ```

`RefMut` is a funny little type that's designed to *look* like a `&mut`, but it's actually a separate thing. It implements [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) and [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html), so it will happily pretend to be a `&mut TreeNode` when needed. But Rust is still inserting calls to `.deref()` in there for you.

Now, why does one work and not the other? Without the type annotation, after `deref` insertion, you get

```
let n = &mut node.borrow_mut();
std::mem::swap(&mut n.deref_mut().left, &mut n.deref_mut().right);
```

So we're trying to call `deref_mut` (which takes a `&mut self`) twice in the same line on the same variable. That's not allowed by Rust's borrow rules, so it fails.

(Note that the `&mut` on the first line simply borrows an owned value for no reason. Temporary lifetime extension lets us get away with this, even though you don't need the `&mut` at all in this case)

Now, on the other hand, if you *do* put in the type annotation, then Rust sees that `borrow_mut` returns a `RefMut<'_, TreeNode>` but you asked for a `&mut TreeNode`, so it inserts the `deref_mut` on the *first* line. You get

```
let n: &mut TreeNode = &mut node.borrow_mut().deref_mut();
std::mem::swap(&mut n.left, &mut n.right);
```

Now the only `deref_mut` call is on the first line. Then, on the second line, we access `n.left` and `n.right`, both *mutably*, simultaneously. It *looks* like we're accessing `n` mutably twice at once, but Rust is actually smart enough to see that we're accessing two disjoint parts of `n` simultaneously, so it allows it. This is called [*borrow splitting*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html). Rust will split borrows on different instance fields, but it's not smart enough to see the split across a `deref_mut` call (function calls could, in principle, do anything, so Rust's borrow checker refuses to try to do advanced reasoning about their return value).